# homomorphisms of infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that each of the following is a homomorphism, and describe its kernel:
>
> - the function $f: \mathbb{R}^*\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$

My proof step: The kernel of $f$ is the set $$k=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^*:f(x)=e\}.$$
Let $a,b \in k$, $f(a)f(b)=f(ab)=ee=e$. I think I'm missing a lot of steps.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: To find $\ker f$ you need to answer the following questions:

1. What is the identity in $\Bbb R_{>0}$? In other words, what **is** the element $e$ of $\Bbb R_{>0}$?
2. What elements of $\Bbb R^*$ are mapped to that identity by $f$?

To show that $f$ is a homomorphism, you need to show that it has the homomorphism property: for all $x,y\in\Bbb R^*$, $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

All of this requires using the definition of $f$.

Comment: the kernel of f is the set K of all the elements of R* which are carried by f onto the neutral element of R>0!! but i'm confusing about identity in R>0? Thanks

Comment: @megan: Okay, let’s start one step further back: what’s the group operation in $\Bbb R_{>0}$?

Comment: commutative, associate

Comment: @megan: I’m not asking for its properties: what operation **is** it? What do we call it? If I apply it to the real numbers $3$ and $6$, what do I get?

Comment: 18? actually, i don't know! sorry!

Comment: @megan: Yes! The group operation in $\Bbb R_{>0}$ is multiplication. That’s also the operation in $\Bbb R^*$. Now, if the operation in $\Bbb R_{>0}$ is multiplication, what positive real number is the neutral element?

Comment: is that e!!!!!!!

Comment: @megan: Not if you mean $e=2.718281828459045\dots$. If you’re just using $e$ as the common symbol for a group’s neutral element, you’re not saying anything about the specific group $\Bbb R_{>0}$. What positive real number $a$ has the property that $ax=xa=x$ for **all** positive real numbers $x$?

Comment: should be 1,,,,,

Comment: @megan: There you go! Yes, the neutral element of $\Bbb R_{>0}$ is $1$, so the kernel of $f$ is the set of all $x\in\Bbb R^*$ such that $f(x)=1$. Remember what function $f$ is; can you say now what the kernel of $f$ is?

Comment: @megan: You’re halfway there: $\ker f$ contains $1$ and one other element. If $f(x)=|x|=1$, then $x$ is $1$ or ...

Comment: kelf(x)=1e, i think so!

Comment: @megan: I’m not sure what you mean by $1e$, but it’s definitely not right. Remember, $\Bbb R^*$ is all real numbers except $0$; that includes the negative numbers. Is there a negative number $x$ such that $|x|=1$?

Comment: when f(x)=1, x=1 or -1, therefore the ker f contain 1 and -1

Comment: @megan: That’s right. There are exactly two members of $\Bbb R^*$ with absolute value $1$, and they are $1$ and $-1$. In other words, the kernel of $f$ is $$\{x\in\Bbb R^*:f(x)=1\}=\{x\in\Bbb R^*:|x|=1\}=\{-1,1\}\;.$$ To finish the problem, you need only show that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R^*$, which means showing that $|xy|=|x|\cdot|y|$; but this is well-known, so probably all that you’re expected to do is explain that this is what ‘$f$ is a homomorphism from $\Bbb R^*$ to $\Bbb R_{>0}$’ means.

Comment: omg! you are really sooo nice! i really thanks your helping. and the most important is i really understand it!!! Thanks so a lot!

Comment: @megan: You’re very welcome. I don’t at all mind spending the time to help someone understand.